# How to run iptables-multi? The destination of the iptables sym-link in EL7.

Tags: iptables

If I look at the `iptables` command on a EL7 environment:

```
bash-4.1# uname -rvos
Linux 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 12 11:03:55 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
```

The symlinks end up in a iptables-multi-1.4.7 process in sbin directory.

```
bash-4.1# namei /sbin/iptables
f: /sbin/iptables
 d /
 d sbin
 l iptables -> /etc/alternatives/iptables.x86_64
   d /
   d etc
   d alternatives
   l iptables.x86_64 -> /sbin/iptables-1.4.7
     d /
     d sbin
     l iptables-1.4.7 -> iptables-multi
       l iptables-multi -> /etc/alternatives/sbin-iptables-multi.x86_64
         d /
         d etc
         d alternatives
         l sbin-iptables-multi.x86_64 -> /sbin/iptables-multi-1.4.7
           d /
           d sbin
           - iptables-multi-1.4.7
```

If I run `iptables-multi-1.4.7` with the same parameters as `iptables`, it gives me an unknown subcommand error.

```
bash-4.1# iptables --list INPUT 1
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

bash-4.1# iptables-multi-1.4.7 --list INPUT 1
iptables multi-purpose version: unknown subcommand "--list"
```

Even though they are the same binary (symlinked to each other) same command line parameters generate different output. What is the right way of invoking `iptables-multi-1.4.7` ?

Comment: The help also does not give a useful information. 
`bash-4.1# iptables-multi-1.4.7 --help` 
`iptables multi-purpose version: unknown subcommand "--help"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bash-4.1# iptables-multi-1.4.7 main --list INPUT 1
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

After stumbling over the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iptables/+/de054f7709b20c97d3e1f16465d5617d9e7683d5/iptables-multi.c#38)  of the iptables-multi I see that it tries to parse the first and the second entries in argv. Passing `main` as the subcommand falls back to the iptables.